# Cloudpebble Error after Watchface installation

Tags: c, cloudpebble, watchface

I've created a C-Watchface on Cloudpebble (which works fine). I'm refactoring it to make the code cleaner.

But I'm getting this Error after the Installation:

```
[FEHLER] ault_handling.c:78: App fault! {1030da8e-9563-4db9-a08f-b8d6d274e8dd} PC: 0x805ea85 LR: ???
```

Is there a way to get a Human Readable Error Message? Do I have to use the SDK for that?

Comment: 'zero Clue' - what about 'ault_handling.c:78'?   Is that not a clue?

Comment: @MartinJames sadly it is not,  'ault_handling.c:78' is in front of every error...

Comment: That line of code must be very buggy:)

Comment: Just as a sanity check verify you use stuff *after* it is created. I've seen many times before a layer is used before it is created

Answer (score 1):

Debugging on Pebble is not an easy task sometimes.

What you're experiencing is PebbleOS telling you that the crash was your app's fault, and that the OS has been a good little boy.

Usually what this means is that you are referencing a `NULL` pointer. I'd recommend using `APP_LOG` throughout parts of your code to check your pointers and make sure you are not destroying anything if you're still using it.

If you are able to break away from the wool sweater of CloudPebble, which keeps you warm but is always a bit itchy, you can use `gdb` to set breakpoints and do much more thorough debugging.

Read more [here](https://developer.pebble.com/guides/debugging/common-runtime-errors/) on common runtime errors, or read more [here](https://developer.pebble.com/guides/debugging/debugging-with-gdb/) for gdb.